# Find previous and next from current record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a big problem to find and next and previous records from current data. I have a data set which is below:

[image]

Need a result which is look like this below:

[image]

Is it possible? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the next and previous shift ids? Is it just an incrementing counter? where does the "profile id" come into play?

Comment: **Next** and **previous** require an **ordering** by something - what do you want to order your data rows by??

Comment: @Mureinik, no increment, it will be selected from previous and next record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD` and `LAG` window functions:

```
SELECT *,
    PreviousShiftProfileID  = LAG(ShiftProfileID) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY CDate),
    NextShiftProfileID      = LEAD(ShiftProfileID) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY CDate)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Hi, if previous or next ShiftProfileID is null then find previous previous  and next next. how can i do that.

Comment: How do I efficiently find the previous non-null ShiftProfileID value?